# Calculate difference in alphabetical evaluation scale

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, datatable

I have an evaluation alphabetical scale like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrsFv.png)

I have a `System.Data.DataTable` that in the column `Current risk` has one of this possible values and in the column `Forward risk` again one of this values and i need to calculate the difference between the Current and the Forward risk and put this result in another column.
The difference is calculated in this way:
Examples:

If Current = AAA and Forward = AA+ --> Difference = -1

If Current  = AAA and Forward = AAA --> Difference = 0

If Current  = AAA and Forward = AA --> Difference = -2

If Current  = AAA and Forward = AA- --> Difference = -3

If Current  = AA+ and Forward = AAA --> Difference = +1

If Current  = AA and Forward = AAA --> Difference = +2

If Current  = A and Forward = AAA --> Difference = +5

I'm using C# .net framework and the only solution i have in mind is with tons of if-then but I would like to know if there is a better and elegant solution for this problem. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an *array* or a `List<T>`, or any sort of *collection* you want really.

```
// insert what ever you like (this was only an example)
private static readonly string[] _array = new[] {"AAA", "AA+", "AA", "A+", "A", "BBB", "BB+"};

private static int Difference(string a, string b)
   => Array.IndexOf(_array, a) - Array.IndexOf(_array, b);

...

Console.WriteLine(Difference("AAA", "A+"));
```

<sub>***Note** : This was only an example and one of many solutions you could create. In this example you can fill the array out as you like or use whatever collection you like. You should have some fault tolerance and validate input etc.*</sub>

Another option would be a Dictionary of string and int.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a `Dictionary` to map risk strings to integers, than you can just process each row in the `DataTable` to update a column.

First, compute the map:

```
var RiskValue = "AAA".AsSingleton()
                     .Concat(new[] { "AA", "A", "BBB", "BB", "B", "CCC" }.SelectMany(r => new[] { "+", "", "-" }.Select(suffix => r + suffix)))
                     .Concat(new[] { "CC", "C", "D" })
                     .Select((r, v) => new { r, v })
                     .ToDictionary(rv => rv.r, rv => rv.v);
```

Then update the difference column with the values:

```
foreach (var r in dt.AsEnumerable())
    r["Risk Difference"] = RiskValue[r.Field<string>("Current risk")] - RiskValue[r.Field<string>("Forward risk")];
```

PS My map computation uses an extension to convert an object to an `IEnumerable<T>` but you could also use `new[] { object }`.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsSingleton<T>(this T first) {
    yield return first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a class and map the values of each risk. Based on the examples shown, for the A group, I came to the conclusion that the value mapping was like this:

- A- Value: 0
- A Value: 1
- A+ Value: 2
- AA- Value: 3
- AA Value: 4
- AA+ Value: 5
- AAA Value:  6

The class to store that data:

```
class Score
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Example code shows adding the 'A' group to the list and also calculating the risk difference correctly.

```
        List<Score> scoreList = new List<Score>();
        scoreList.Add(new Score { Name = "A-", Value = 0 });
        scoreList.Add(new Score { Name = "A", Value = 1 });
        scoreList.Add(new Score { Name = "A+", Value = 2 });
        scoreList.Add(new Score { Name = "AA-", Value = 3 });
        scoreList.Add(new Score { Name = "AA", Value = 4 });
        scoreList.Add(new Score { Name = "AA+", Value = 5 });
        scoreList.Add(new Score { Name = "AAA", Value = 6 });

        //If Current = AAA and Forward = AA+ --> Difference = -1
        var difference = scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AA+").Value - scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AAA").Value;

        //If Current = AAA and Forward = AAA-- > Difference = 0
        var difference1 = scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AAA").Value - scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AAA").Value;

        //If Current = AAA and Forward = AA-- > Difference = -2
        var difference2 = scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AA").Value - scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AAA").Value;

        //If Current = AAA and Forward = AA - --> Difference = -3
        var difference3 = scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AA-").Value - scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AAA").Value;

        //If Current = AA + and Forward = AAA-- > Difference = +1
        var difference4 = scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AAA").Value - scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AA+").Value;

        //If Current = AA and Forward = AAA-- > Difference = +2
        var difference5 = scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AAA").Value - scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AA").Value;

        //If Current = A and Forward = AAA-- > Difference = +5
        var difference6 = scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "AAA").Value - scoreList.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Name == "A").Value;
```

Hope this helps get you started.